# What is wrong with my Filter and Map function as its not filtering the correct item inside my React Component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

Here is are my menu items, and I want to filter only the Drinks in a drink Component, I am displaying both the 'Drinks' and 'Eat' under categories. And my goal is to only filter and extract the 'Drinks' as I am displaying the drinks on its own component.

Here is my data:

```
const MenuItems: MenuItems[] = [
  {
    category: "Drinks",
    price: 2,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "Coffee",
    description: "A blend of coffee beans from La Bolsa in Colombia.",
  },
  {
    category: "Drinks",
    price: 2,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "OJ",
    description: "Cold pressed and freshely squeezed orange juice.",
  },
  {
    category: "Drinks",
    price: 2,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "Tea",
    description: "Cold pressed and freshely squeezed orange juice.",
  },
  {
    category: "Drinks",
    price: 2,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "Iced",
    description: "Choice of Earl Grey, GreenTea, Chamomile, or Peppermint.",
  },
  {
    category: "Drinks",
    price: 4,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "Latte",
    description: "2 shots of espresso served with steamed milk of choice.",
  },
  {
    category: "Eats",
    price: 14,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "FCC Classic",
    description:
      "Three cage-free eggs cooked any style and with bacon. Includes hash browns and toast.",
  },
  {
    category: "Eats",
    price: 14,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "3 Egg Omelet",
    description:
      "Three cage-free eggs with Mushrooms, Peppers, Onions. Served with hash browns and toast.",
  },
  {
    category: "Eats",
    price: 14,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "Corned Beef Hash",
    description:
      "Our signature shredded hash mixed with grass-fed, dry-rubbed, corned beef, caramelized poblanos and onions, topped with two cage-free eggs; your style, & toast.",
  },
  {
    category: "Eats",
    price: 12,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "OMG French Toast!",
    description:
      "Fresh brioche stuffed with mascarpone and topped with vanilla crème, caramel, fresh strawberries, and toasted coconut.",
  },
  {
    category: "Eats",
    price: 9,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "Buttermilk Pancakes",
    description:
      "Buttermilk pancakes topped with whipped butter and powdered sugar served with Slopeside Pure Vermont Maple Syrup.",
  },
  {
    category: "Eats",
    price: 12,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "FCC Ham Benedict",
    description:
      "Our Signature English muffin topped with fresh smashed avocado, Parmesan cheese, ripened tomatoes, two poached cage free-eggs, smoked cheddar hollandaise and everything spice.",
  },
  {
    category: "Eats",
    price: 12,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "Avocado Benny",
    description:
      "Our Signature English muffin topped with fresh smashed avocado, Parmesan cheese, ripened tomatoes, two poached cage free-eggs, smoked cheddar hollandaise and everything spice.",
  },
  {
    category: "Eats",
    price: 13,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "FCC Avocado Toast",
    description:
      "Rustic bread toasted with olive oil, smashed avocado, onion honey jam, and roasted tomato. Topped with two cage-free sunny side up eggs with a side Dijon citronette, Spiced Pepitas & Parmesan-dressed greens.",
  },
  {
    category: "Eats",
    price: 12,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "Veggie Smash",
    description:
      "Griddled, smashed sweet potatoes, a cage-free poached egg, avocado, pickled onions, paprika, drizzled with black pepper maple syrup and topped with our asparagus mushroom salad.",
  },
  {
    category: "Eats",
    price: 13,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "Garden Omelet",
    description:
      "Three cage-free eggs with sauteed asparagus, mushrooms, zucchini and red bell peppers. Topped with chili-lime seasoned avocado and goat cheese.",
  },
  {
    category: "Eats",
    price: 12,
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlsacnkot/image/upload/v1634070429/test.jpg",
    name: "Tofu Veggie Scramble",
    description:
      "Tofu seasoned with onion powder, salt & pepper; scrambled with choice of three fillings, served with hash browns and toast.",
  },
];
export default MenuItems;
interface MenuItems {
  category: string;
  price: number;
  url: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
}
```

Here is my Drinks Component

```
import MenuItems from "./MenuItems";

const Drinks = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.MenuItems.name} </div>;
};

export default Drinks;
```

Here is my main Menu Component, and my map and filter functions.

```
      <div>
        {MenuItems.filter((item) => "Drinks").map((item) => {
          return <Drinks MenuItems={item} />;
        })}
      </div>
```

Output:

Coffee
OJ
Tea
Iced
Latte
FCC Classic
3 Egg Omelet
Corned Beef Hash
OMG French Toast!
Buttermilk Pancakes
FCC Ham Benedict
Avocado Benny
FCC Avocado Toast
Veggie Smash
Garden Omelet
Tofu Veggie Scramble

Only want the "drinks" to show, not the "Eats".

Comment: `MenuItems.filter((item) => "Drinks")` should be `MenuItems.filter((item) => item.category === "Drinks")`

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MenuItems.filter((item) => "Drinks")` return always `true`

What you should be doing is comparing the category to drinks.

`MenuItems.filter((item) => item.category === "Drinks")`